# PhantomJS dropping cookies on 302 redirect

Tags: redirect, cookies, phantomjs, spookyjs

I'm using the SpookyJS node library to walk through a web flow. Some of the cookies that I'm supposed to have aren't being set on a 302 redirect. Is there any knowledge as to whether this is a PhantomJS or SpookyJS problem?

Comment: This is happening to me as well (I suspect, anyway). It seems to be when I have 2 specs in a row that sign in a user, the 2nd time around, the user does not get signed in. Please update this if you figure it out. FWIW I'm using ruby/capybara/poltergeist so it's probably not spookyjs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PhantomJS problem. Apparently it doesn't handle redirects very well. 
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389

I've been using casper for my project, so when I ran into this issue I had to use slimerjs as my engine to make things work.